# Git Smart HTTP push permisisons failure

Tags: linux, git, apache, permissions, push

I am new to Git and I'm trying to get Git on the server.  I installed Git and httpd on Centos 7.  I created a base shared project on the server using

git init --bare --shared product/tools/DCU.git

[core]

```
    repositoryformatversion = 0

    filemode = true

    bare = true

    sharedrepository = 1
```

[receive]

```
    denyNonFastforwards = true
```

When I push, git push DCU master I get the following error:

remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects

remote: fatal: failed to write object

error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit

My perms on the project are:

total 24
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 apache staff  196 Aug 22 16:56 config
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 apache staff   73 Aug 22 15:28 description
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 apache staff   23 Aug 22 15:28 HEAD
drwxrwxr-x.  2 apache staff 4096 Aug 22 15:28 hooks
drwxrwxr-x.  2 apache staff   20 Aug 22 15:28 info
drwxrwxr-x. 65 apache staff 4096 Aug 22 16:50 objects
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 apache staff   98 Aug 22 15:29 packed-refs
drwxrwxr-x.  4 apache staff   29 Aug 22 15:29 refs

cd objects/

total 12
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 06
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 08
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   96 Aug 22 15:28 0a
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 17
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 19
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 1c
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 24
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 29
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff 4096 Aug 22 15:28 30
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 32
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 33
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 3d
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 3f
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 41
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 4b
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 57
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 5a
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 5d
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 5f
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 64
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 65
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff 4096 Aug 22 15:28 69
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 6d
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 70
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 74
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 7a
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 7b
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 7c
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 84
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 89
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 8a
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 8c
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 93
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 9d
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 a0
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 a2
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff 4096 Aug 22 15:28 a3
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 a6
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 ab
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 af
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 b1
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 b7
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 b8
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 c3
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 c8
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   96 Aug 22 15:28 c9
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 cb
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:28 cf
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:29 d1
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:29 d8
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:29 d9
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:29 db
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:29 dc
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:29 e1
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:29 e7
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:29 e9
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:29 ea
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:29 ed
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:29 f0
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:29 f3
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff   51 Aug 22 15:29 f5
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff    6 Aug 22 15:29 info
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache staff    6 Aug 22 15:29 pack

My apache and git users are both in the staff group, and staff group if there default group.  I have also tried to use the set group id bits but to no avail.  http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html

[root@services-git DataConversion.git]# groups apache

apache : staff git

[root@services-git DataConversion.git]# groups git

git : staff apache

What user is Git trying to write as?  I used htpasswd to create a user and password (git/git), and the authentication works when I try and push, but this is just at the http level, correct?  This authentication is not at the OS level, that is my understanding anyway.  I am just not sure which user Git is trying to use.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: I installed Gitlab community, it's an all in one free solution.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Gitlab community, it's an all in one free solution.  I am done messing around with trying to get git to work on my own.